# How do I generate XML from XMLBuilder using a .xml.builder file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby, templates

I have started using xml builder templates for most of my model. I need to find a generic way to build XML outside of a render which uses the .xml.builder template instead of the generic .to_xml method provided in the model

I gather that I will have to override the default to_xml (or add a to_my_xml), but I am unable to see how to get XMLBuilder to use my .builder files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Add a `respond_to` block in your controller so that the appropriate template is rendered according to the requested format. For example:

```
def show
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # renders show.html.erb
    format.xml  # renders show.xml.builder
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I already have a respond block, but need to know the XML that will be generated by the respond_to block before it runs as I need to pass this XML as an XMPP message. The render in the respond_to block uses a .xml.builder template which I am trying to mimic.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for how to create xml using builder then this is how you can do it

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'builder'
builder = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:indent=>2)
builder.instruct! :xml, :version=>"1.0", :encoding=>"UTF-8"
builder.my_elements do |e|
  builder.myitem {|element| element.my_element_name('element_value')}
end

#=>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<my_elements>
  <myitem>
    <my_element_name>element_value</my_element_name>
  </myitem>
</my_elements>
```

Comment: Hi Naz - thanks for the that.

The key thing though is that I want to use the same template file that render uses to generate the XML.

So, my respond_to block looks like this:

respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.xml { render :template => "slides/slides_and_comments.xml.builder"}
end

How do I get XmlBuilder to use the "slides/slides_and_comments.xml.builder" template?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I just had to solve this problem.  Here is how I got it to work, comments inline ...

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # this must be included to use tag helpers like cdata_block, etc ...
  include :Helpers::TagHelper

  def preview_xml
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    # You must set up a instance variable named 'xml'
    xml = ::Builder::XmlMarkup.new(indent: 2)

    builder_file = File.read(::Rails.root.to_s + '/app/views/posts/show.xml.builder')

    require 'builder'

    # instance_eval evaluates the file within the context of the current instance -- so the
    # xml variable we just set will be accessable within the builder_file
    instance_eval builder_file

    @tag_xml = xml.target!
  end

end
```

Comment: you might want to put the 'require' above the ::builder constant