# How to generate XML file using Ruby and Builder::XMLMarkup templates?

Tags: ruby, xml, templates

As you all know, with Rails it is possible to use Builder::XMLMarkup templates to provide an http reponse in XML format instead of HTML (with the respond_to command). My problem is that I would like to use the Builder::XMLMarkup templating system not with Rails but with Ruby only (i.e. a standalone program that generates/outputs an XML file from an XML template). The question is then twofold:

1. How do I tell the Ruby program which is the template I want to use? and
2. How do I tell the Builder class which is the output XML file ?

There is already a similar answer to that in Stackoverflow ([How do I generate XML from XMLBuilder using a .xml.builder file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176287/how-do-i-generate-xml-from-xmlbuilder-using-a-xml-builder-file)), but I am afraid it is only valid for Rails.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a simple example showing the basics:

```
require 'builder'

@received_data = {:books => [{ :author => "John Doe", :title => "Doeisms" }, { :author => "Jane Doe", :title => "Doeisms II" }]}
@output = ""
xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:target => @output, :indent => 1)

xml.instruct!
xml.books do
  @received_data[:books].each do |book|
    xml.book do
      xml.title book[:title]
      xml.author book[:author]
    end
  end
end
```

The @output object will contain your xml markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
 <book>
  <title>Doeisms</title>
  <author>John Doe</author>
 </book>
 <book>
  <title>Doeisms II</title>
  <author>Jane Doe</author>
 </book>
</books>
```

The Builder docs at [github.com](https://github.com/jimweirich/builder) provide more examples and links to more documentation.

To select a specific template, you could pass arguments to your program for this decision.

Anyway, I prefer to use [libxml-ruby](https://xml4r.github.io/libxml-ruby/) to parse and build XML documents, but that's a matter of taste.

Comment: Yes I have read it but I could not see any mention in how to actually create an XML using Builder templates with Ruby (not Rails)...

Comment: I've expanded somewhat the answer. Take a look.

Comment: I think he would like to know how to get it to the final file on the disk.

Answer (score 1):

I used [Tilt](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt) to do (the first part of) this.  It's really easy:

```
require 'builder'
require 'tilt'
template = Tilt.new('templates/foo.builder')
output = template.render
```

That will get you a string representation of your xml.  At that point you can write it out  to disk yourself.